# How do I do a type ignore on a multi-line piece of code in python?

Tags: formatting, pylint

I've recently started using pylint to catch errors and bad styling in my code. I've found that there are some things I need to get pylint to ignore as it complains when it shouldn't. I know that `# type: ignore` does this, but I'm having problems making it work with a line of code that doesn't fit onto a single line.

I'm trying to do a type ignore on a section of code that is over multiple lines. It looks something like:

```py
if thing == this.that.something_else['name'] \ 
    and this.that.something_else['age'] == 0
```

and I want to do:

```py
if thing == this.that.something_else['name'] \ # type: ignore
    and this.that.something_else['age'] == 0 # type: ignore
```

but the first half of the line ends with `\` so the first type ignore doesn't work. How can I write this so that it can ignore both parts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using pylint ? It that's the case then `# type: ignore` is not the way to ignore false positives in pylint, it's `# pylint: disable=my-message-name`. You can disable on multiple line like this:

```
# pylint: disable=my-message-name
if thing == this.that.something_else['name'] \ 
    and this.that.something_else['age'] == 0
# pylint: enable=my-message-name
```

Or maybe

```
# pylint: disable-next=my-message-name
if thing == this.that.something_else['name'] and this.that.something_else['age'] == 0
```

More detail in the [message control doc](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/messages/message_control.html)